# Bayesian Data Analysis Problem 4 b: normal approximation of football point outcomes

Tags: self-study

The problem is as follows (Ch 1, problem 4 b, p. 27, 3rd edition):

> There were twelve games with point spreads of 8 points; the outcomes
>   in those games the point difference was −7, −5, −3, −3, 1, 6, 7, 13, 15, 16, 20, and 21,
>   with positive values indicating wins for the favorite after including the point spread.
>
> Use a normal distribution to approximate the distribution of (outcome
>   - point spread)

[The solution](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/solutions2.pdf) models the distribution as $N \sim (0, 13.86^2)$.

- How do we know that the mean is centered at 0? Are we assuming that the point spread is an unbiased estimate of the outcome?
- Why is the standard deviation 13.86? The (population) standard deviation is 10.1 instead.

  ```
  sd(c(-7, -5, -3, -3, 1, 6, 7, 13, 15, 16, 20, 21) - 8)
  # 10.1
  ```

Reference: Gelman, Andrew, et al. Bayesian data analysis. Vol. 3. Boca Raton, FL, USA: Chapman & Hall/CRC, 2014.

Comment: I don't see any basis in the text for using 13.86; the text (p13-16) uses 14 as the assumed value of $\sigma$ (which seems to describe the overall data set well). Presumably 13.86 comes from a calculation based on the whole of the sample\* - presumably the sample standard deviation - but the text gives no reason to do that). If I was trying to write a solution for this exercise, I'd have followed the text and assumed that 14 was a suitable standard deviation for the subset. $\quad$ \* possibly excluding a subset as described in some parts of the text

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the football problem is an extension of a football example in the main text, which describes more about the distribution as follows (p. 15)

> The sample mean of the 672 values of d is 0.07, and **the sample
>   standard deviation is 13.86**, suggesting that the results of football
>   games are approximately normal with **mean equal to the point spread** and
>   standard deviation nearly 14 points (two converted touchdowns).